# Three Problems that I can not resolve in python

Tags: python

So I am creating a new simple game to practice my python programming, it is a point/score system that I wanted to implement. I also wanted to make it so it's intelligent by asking the user if it wants to play. So I have three problems at the moment, when I ask the user if it wants to play I wasn't sure what to do if they said no or "n" if they didn't want to play, instead what happens is that it just continues playing then crashes saying "n" is not defined. The second problem that I have is when the user puts the right answer for the random function I put `print("You guessed it right!")` but it just prints a bunch of them. My third and final problem is the point system, I wasn't sure if it executed after the million printed statements, but I'll see after I fix it.

Here is my game

```
import random
total_tries = 4
score = 0
print("Welcome to Guess the number game!")
answer = input("Would you like to play? y/n: ")
if answer == "y":
    n = (random.randrange(1, 10))
guess = int(input("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20: "))
while n!= guess:
    if guess < n:
        total_tries - 1
        print("That is too low!")
        guess = int(input("Enter a number again: "))
    elif guess > n:
        print("That is too high")
        total_tries - 1
        guess = int(input("Enter a number again: "))
    else:
        break
while n == guess:
    score = +1
   print("You guessed it right!")

if total_tries == 0:
    print("Thank you for playing, you got", score, "questions correct.")
mark = (score/total_tries) * 100
print("Mark:", str(mark) + ""%"")
print("Goodbye")
```

Error when putting no for playing:

```
while n!= guess:
NameError: name 'n' is not defined
```

Comment: Where is `n` defined when `answer` is not `"y"`? That is, what do you expect `n` to be when `while n!= guess` is reached if the user does not enter `"y"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1 you want the system to exit when the user says no. I would do this by using sys.exit to kill the code.

```
import sys
...
answer = input("Would you like to play? y/n: ")
if answer == "y":
    n = (random.randrange(1, 10))**strong text**
else:
    sys.exit('User does not want to play, exiting')
```

For problem 2 you are getting your print statement a million times because you're failing to exit. In the code below n is always equal to guess because you never change n. You don't need a while statement here because you already know you only left the above section when n started to equal guess. Another issue to think about. How will you make it stop when the number of turns runs out?

```
while n == guess:
    score = +1
    print("You guessed it right!")
```

For the third question, think about what will happen here if the number of turns reaches 0.

```
if total_tries == 0:
    print("Thank you for playing, you got", score, "questions correct.")
mark = (score/total_tries) * 100
```

In particular, what would happen when you try to calculate mark?

Answer (score 0):

This condition will only trigger when answer is "y"

```
if answer == "y":
    n = (random.randrange(1, 10))
```

Remove this and the code will run or modify it as such

```
if answer == "y":
    n = (random.randrange(1, 10))
elif answer == "n"
    # set n to some other value
```

Comment: Thank you I fixed that error!